# border-color change in table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a very simple HTML table like below:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr><!-- Table Row -->
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

that I want when I hover on each of the cells, the borders of the cell could change color. So I wrote the following CSS trying to achieve the effect:

```
table{
position: absolute;

font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:white;
font-size:12px;
border:white 1px solid;

-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;

-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;

width: 100%;
height: 100%%;
}

table tr {
text-align: center;
padding-left:20px;
}

table td {
padding:18px;
border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
width: 33%;
height: 50%;
background-color: black;
}

table td:hover{
  border:blue 1px solid;
}
```

This code works, but not perfectly. It works great when I hover on the cells 1, 2, 3 (as numbered in the html), BUT when I hover, for example, on cell 4 5 6, the **top border** of the cell is not showing blue. I think the top borders of them are overlayed by the bottom borders of the cells above.

Is there a work around to this issue?

Comment: You've not provided complete css

Comment: Strange! Working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/RfNHg/

Comment: I believe asker's table has `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table http://jsfiddle.net/9URAd/

Comment: Even with the updated code, it seems to work fine mate.

Comment: Its work fine, no any problem in this code.

Comment: is it regarding browser compatibility issue or something. It works fine. Please give a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With border-collapse set to collapse, the solution would be to use an inset border for all the cells, and a solid border for the cell that the mouse hovers over. Here's the suggested CSS in action: http://jsfiddle.net/QmHGG/

The following is the CSS that was applied to the table:

```
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px inset black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Warning: I believe this applies to ALL tables on a given web-page. It's probably better to limit to the scope. (Samples welcome.)